# Attach file in email using Azure Data Factory pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to attach the error file present in ADLS with failure emails sent by web activity to the different teams using the pipeline.

I don't want to use Logic Apps for this.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In Data Factory you have an activity type called as Custom Activity you will find it under batch services. You have to write a C# script which will be executed when you run this activity. Refer to this link for the code -> link. You can pass any parameter to this custom activity with extended properties link. Using extended properties you can pass the path of adls file.

Comment: can you please explain a little bit

Comment: In Data Factory you have an activity type called as Custom Activity you will find it under batch services. You have to write a C# script which will be executed when you run this activity. Refer to this link for the code -> [link(]http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-email-attachment.htm). You can pass any parameter to this custom activity with extended properties [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.datafactory.models.customactivity.extendedproperties?view=azure-dotnet). Using extended properties you can pass the path of adls file.

Comment: @Amirparkar please add this comment to your answer to make it complete and understandable. Comments get deleted over time.